# Trouble with reading from text file

Tags: batch-file

My goal is to have a program that saves 6 variables (q,d,n,p,tc,td) in a text file each time one is updated (Success) and when reopened will automatically set the variables based on the text file. So if tc equaled 13 when it last closed, if I opened it a week later it would still equal 13. (assuming the text file goes un-touched)
The problem happens when I try to run this bit of code:

```
:Load
set v=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("SavedData.txt") do (
set /a var+=1
set var!v!=%%a
)
set q=%var1%
set d=%var2%
set n=%var3%
set p=%var4%
set td=%var5%
set tc=%var6%
goto main
```

it gives the following error:

```
9 was unexpected at this time.
```

Any ideas? (btw, when the error was displayed none of the values equaled 9)

**EDIT:** I got it working, but now each variable has an extra space at the end which I want removed so it can function properly.

I got it working by typing `set /a v+=1` instead of `set /a var+=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error message is occurring where you think it is, but I do see a bug in your code. You are incrementing `var` when you intend to increment `v`. I don't see how that bug can give the error message you describe, but it obviously will cause problems, and could possibly lead to the error elsewhere in your code.

Your Load routine could be much simpler.

```
:Load
<"SavedData.txt" (for %%V in (q d n p td tc) do set /p "%%V=")
```

Answer (score 1):

As dbenham said, your load routine could be much simpler. This answer will not discuss how to get it simpler as you should probably just look up (assuming debnham's answer gets more upvotes than mine). What this answer will tell you is why you have extra spaces in your variable's values.

Now, the only reason I can think of why this is happening is because somewhere in your code (probably the `:save` sequence), you have code looking like this:

```
echo value_of_q >> "SavedData.txt"
::More stuff here...
```

The problem is the space before the end of your statement (`echo value_of_q`) and the redirection (`>> "SavedData.txt"`). This would append the output of your command (including any spaces) to the end of `SavedData.txt`.

Now, you could avoid this by one of two options (or both).

Option 1.
You trim the spaces. Make it `echo value_of_q>> "SavedData.txt` instead of what you had.

Option 2.
Assuming the values of the variables are on separate lines, you can remove the `delims` option within your `for` loop (you can also remove the `usebackq` option as well).

So, your `for` loop will look more like...

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("SavedData.txt") do (
    ::Rest of your code here...
    ::Oh, and your code blocks should be indented as well.
)
```

As you can see, I changed the `%%a` to `%%i`, this isn't necessary for your loop, but it is good practice as it may keep away errors in the future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ...And I made a typo in dbenham's name. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach is to make the save file a `.bat` one instead of a `.txt` file by including complete `set` commands instead of just variable values; this have the advantage that the load code does not rely on the order of the saved values (nor the save code either). For example, this would be the code to save the variables:

```
:Save
(for %%v in (q d n p td tc) do echo set %%v=!%%v!) > "SavedData.bat"
```

And this would be the code to recover the saved values:

```
:Load
call "SavedData.bat"
```

Antonio

Comment: Great Idea! I like to use the text files though, especially for larger things, it's smaller then the *.bat's